# GKE cluster and Steam master server

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I need to specify a list of IP ranges in Steamworks to mark them as the official servers of my game. How can I create a cluster that creates nodes only in a constant range of external IP addresses? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information your infrastructure. But I can assume, that you should [reserve IP addresses in Google Cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address). Then you should use them in your GKE installation, as IP address for Ingress controller or for Service.